# Why is the protobuf asked to bump to 4.21.3 from 3.5.0 since v1.49.0 for gRPC

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I found the required protobuf version was bumped to 4.21.3 from 3.5.0 since v1.49.0:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.49.0-pre1/requirements.txt

```
# GRPC Python setup requirements
coverage>=4.0
cython>=0.29.8
protobuf>=4.21.3,<5.0dev
six>=1.10
wheel>=0.29
```

May I ask which new feature of protobuf in 4.21.3 is required by gRPC?

Thanks.

BR/Amber

We would like to evaluate if the protobuf upgrading is must-to-do.

BR/Amber

Comment: not sure what you are trying to ask

Comment: There is some problem in upgrading protobuf in my setup, and the version in use is 3.6.1. Want to evaluate where the risk is by not upgrading protobuf to the required version 4.21.3.

Answer (score 1):

In general, code generated by a version of the Protobuf code generator needs the same or newer Protobuf runtime and internally to gRPC there are generated protos.

Comment: Want to evaluate the risk not upgrading protobuf version.

Comment: Usually gRPC tries to bump the version of Protobuf every time Protobuf has a new release to make two libraries work together. But gRPC can work with older versions of Protobuf in general. You can try using older protobuf with the latest gRPC. Sometimes you might see build errors because of breaking changes Protobuf sometimes introduced. Note that protobuf introduced two major things recently; new Abseil dependency and Cord support. Those may prevent you from pairing new gRPC and old Protobuf but you can try it.